# How to use Entity Framework with adding a new database for every new client?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a project which requires a separate database for each client. We are using EF to create interaction between database and our API.

I am not sure how to use Entity Framework every time I create a new database. What shall be the correct way of doing this?

I am getting this idea to have a config file where I can enter the entry of this new database which will then allow the users to use the system but don't know how to implement this. Can someone please suggest? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Entity Framework is designed to retrieve and store data - it's definitely **not** a SQL Server management framework. For creating separate databases, you should use straight ADO.NET with raw SQL statements.

Comment: If you use database-per-tenant then you can feed the EF DbContext a connection string (rather than a connection string name from the .config file)  where it can find/create the database. This assumes that the schema does not change per tenant. (either schema name or schema definition.) I've forked the Mehdime DBContextScope to accommodate both db-per-tenant and schema-per-tenant implementations for a unit of work pattern. Consider starting with a master database/context to organize your tenants details including the connection strings.